# How to pass image in nested postman request?

Tags: django-rest-framework, postman

I'm tring to pass a request for which mutiple image is associted...
I'm trying the send the below request please help me to pass image in the nested request.

```
{
    "name": "any name",
    "category": 1,
    "price": 19000,
    "description": "Please Purchase",
    "count": 5,
    "image": [
        {
        "image" : i??
        }
    ]  
}
```

Comment: You can't send images using json. you need to use form data

Comment: but the fields are nested @ahmedosama how can we send it.?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: you need to use form data

Secondly: use an array-like syntax like this: `images[0][image] = ??`

Comment: I need data in the form by as images[0][image] in post-man ?

Comment: What do you mean ?